# Timeout Updating records being read by a SQLDatareader (Sometimes)

Tags: ado.net, timeout, sql-update, sqldatareader

**The Setup**

I have a simple SQLDataReader configured to bring back every row in a given table.

I am using a SQLDataReader because I'm looking to keep my memory footprint relatively low.

For Each row retrieved, I'm applying a simple alteration to some of the data and using this as the basis of an update which I execute immediately.

In this way I can apply a simple calculated function to every record in a a table.

**When does it work?**

This works fine on my local database. It also works fine on a test database located on another server.

**When does it not work?**

If I restore a copy of our live database, the process fails to execute properly, encountering a Timeout on the very first attempt to perform an update.

**What is different?**

The only difference between LiveBackup and Test would seem to be the number of records in it. The Test database has 4823 and LiveBackup has 10182 records.

Further, if I introduce criteria into the SQLDataReader such that it retrieves a limited number of records (1000 or so) from the LiveBackup system, it starts working immediately

**Theories**

It seems likely that there is some kind of lock being introduced, but really I can't see where.

I appreciate that I could simply break the records down into batches of 1000, but that would still leave me not understanding what exactly is causing my problem.

**Why does the timeout occur on the update (which is addressing a single record) when my SQLDatareader addresses a large number of records?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server page sizes are 8K, so maybe the locking changes when you try to read over one page?

Bruce Barker's reply here has some hints to avoid the situation:
http://www.dotnet247.com/247reference/msgs/15/76467.aspx

But as you pointed out, fetching the rows to update in batches is a step forward :-)

Personally if you *have* to get the data locally to update, I'd populate an old fashioned DataSet/DataTable in batches and also use a DataAdapter. Then you can get some additional efficiency in writing the updates back in batches too:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aadf8fk2.aspx

Did you already decide that doing the update in TSQL is not possible?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have different isolation/row-locking levels between the different environments, which is why you're getting the different behaviour (or SQL Server chooses a different strategy the more rows there are). It looks as though the query that brings back every row in the table is locking the table in your live database.

The row-locking behaviour can be set:

- [against the database as a whole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188277.aspx),
- or just [on the connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx),
- or even on an individual query e.g. `SELECT * FROM MyTable WITH (NOLOCK)`

(Note therefore this is more a SQL Server question than anything to do with ADO.NET)